# How to display GitHub actions last run date in badge

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I have some cron scheduled GitHub actions and want to know the last run date in README.

Now I have the badge but it lacks the date information.

I know I can edit the README file in the actions but I don't like this approach.

Comment: Something like that doesn't seem to be available. However, you might want to look at https://shields.io/badges.